# Getting an error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72})

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error. It seems like the promise is unresolved.
However, I am unsure how to fix this...
I am using Async Storage

Error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}).

Here is my code

```
const ProfileStackScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (<ProfileStack.Navigator>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name= {"Profile"} component={Profile}
    options ={{
      title: AsyncStorage.getItem('username'),
      headerRight: () => (
          <Icon name="cog" color={"grey"} size={26} style={{marginRight: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}/>
      ),
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon name="users" color={"grey"} size={23} style={{marginLeft: 20}}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ManageFriends")}/>
    )
    }}/>
    <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
    <ManageFriendsStack.Screen name="ManageFriends" component={ManageFriends}/>
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>);
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I noticed I can do something like this

```
const ProfileStackScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('username').then(name => {
    //comment
    console.log(name);
  });
  return (<ProfileStack.Navigator>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name= {"Profile"} component={Profile}
    options ={{
      title: "hi",
      headerRight: () => (
          <Icon name="cog" color={"grey"} size={26} style={{marginRight: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}/>
      ),
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon name="users" color={"grey"} size={23} style={{marginLeft: 20}}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ManageFriends")}/>
    )
    }}/>
    <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
    <ManageFriendsStack.Screen name="ManageFriends" component={ManageFriends}/>
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>);
}
```

However, I want to set the name inside my title (line 5) I cant do this.setState since I get (setState of undefined) and I can't put return inside the //comment since I get "cant find return statement"

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

**EDIT 2**

Tried adding navigation.setOptions

```
const ProfileStackScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('username').then(name => {
    navigation.setOptions({title: name});
  });
  return (<ProfileStack.Navigator>
    <ProfileStack.Screen name= {"Profile"} component={Profile}
    options ={{
      headerRight: () => (
          <Icon name="cog" color={"grey"} size={26} style={{marginRight: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}/>
      ),
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon name="users" color={"grey"} size={23} style={{marginLeft: 20}}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ManageFriends")}/>
    )
    }}/>
    <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
    <ManageFriendsStack.Screen name="ManageFriends" component={ManageFriends}/>
  </ProfileStack.Navigator>);
}
```

However, it gets override by the `name= {"Profile"}` It shows Profile instead of my username.

Comment: this kind of object {_40, _65, _55, _72} is probably cause you are not waiting for an async request to be completed, you say that you are using async storage but i don't see any in your shared code

Comment: @Charlie It is in line 5, I edited my post. Any ideas how I can modify my code to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setOptions in component itself, navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Some title' })

As stated [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions):

> It's often necessary to update the options configuration for the
>   active screen from the mounted screen component itself. We can do this
>   using navigation.setOptions

Comment: I am still getting the same error. It seems like it is because every time i use `() => {// AsyncStorage calll}`, I get this error.  Without arrow function works fine. However, I need the arrow function for this. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: what about pulling the AsyncStorage request outside of this? have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by pulling the AsyncStorage request? I tried creating a function in another file and exporting/importing the function but same error :(  I've been stuck on this for a while now...

Comment: ok here is another idea, use setOptions in component itself, navigation.setOptions({ title: 'Updated!' }) https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions

Comment: which in your case would be

Comment: const title = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username'); navigation.setOptions({ title })

Comment: That is a good idea, However, it seems like it is getting overrided by the `name= {"Profile"}` Your code still gives me the same error so I modified it to my code

Comment: use the setOptions in component Profile

Comment: I am confused what you mean by setOptions in component Profile. Didn't i do that in my Edit: 2 ?

Comment: i mean in component not in stacks declarations

Comment: Ahh got it! Thank you